# Idiomatic way of implementing global error handler in http4k

Tags: kotlin, http4k

I tried to find an answer in project's documentation but couldn't find anything useful.

What is the best practice to implement a global error handler that captures all the exceptions and returns appropriate http status based on the exception type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you should implement an http4k `Filter`.

The API docs have a list of all the current filters that are implemented: https://www.http4k.org/api/org.http4k.filter/

Specifically for this, you want to add a `ServerFilters.CatchAll` into your filter chain. If you click through you can see the implementation:

https://www.http4k.org/api/org.http4k.filter/-server-filters/-catch-all/

Comment: Developers probably shouldn't use CatchAll out of the box, as it leaks stack traces into the response. You can now configure its error behaviour to log uncaught exceptions.